# Given basis for a Lie algebra, what is one for its Universal Central Extension

Tags: lie-algebras

Given that I have an infinite basis for a Lie algebra $L$, and the information that $M$ is its Universal Central Extension, is $M$ unique? If so, what is the basis of $M$ in terms of that of $L$?

Comment: Uniqueness follow from the universal property as usual. This is proved in every textbook which treats the subject.

Comment: Af for what is a basis of the universal extension, well... it depends on the Lie álgebra! I cannot imagine what sort of answer you expect here.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that since I am largely ignorant of anything Category theoretic. Can we say something about the basis of $M$ then?

Comment: I have a basis for $L$, so I know all the required Lie brackets. But when I look at $M$, there will be an additional central term right? To rephrase my question -- does the "universality" of $M$ as a central extension of $L$ impose any sort of condition on the cocyle that will appear as the coefficient of the central term?

Comment: The central extensión is completely determined in terms of the cohomology of the álgebra. You could do worse than read the relevant section in Weibel's book on homological algebra.

Comment: In particular, there may be one or several central terms in the extension, and they are described by cohomology.

Comment: Ok @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez. Thanks for your help. If you post this as an answer, I will happy to tag this question as solved!